# what do the difference between using GPU or CPU for rendering?

Tags: rendering, gpu, osx

I wanted to speed up my rendering time, and I found that using GPU speed up a lot. But I don't have a very fast GPU (NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB), so I want to know what do the difference between using GPU or CPU, so I would compare my CPU (2,66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo) with my GPU (NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gpu's have many cores (yours may have 72 cores) but they run at lower speed (frequency) .Gpu cores can understand simpier instructions that a cpu core can understand.Cpu has much less cores than gpu cores but they run at higher frequency and they understand complex set of instructions.These are some key differences.

Comment: To speed even further the rendering with your gpu be sure to set the rendering tile to something big like 1000*1000 this will speed it a lot

Comment: So for me it's better to use CPU or GPU? @xlxs

Comment: @Fly_7113 It depends . Some complex scenes will crash if you render them on your gpu (because they will need more memory than your gpu has(dedicated + dynamic).

Comment: Also smoke rendering at gpu isnt corrently supported (at cycles).

Comment: I have a scene with a lot of emitting panel and a reflecting surface and also a text which appears so use mix shaders node and the camera moves a lot... If you want I can upload the blend file @xlxs

Comment: Just test it both ways. If CPU is faster, use CPU. If GPU is faster, use GPU (provided its limitations don't get in your way). You can install the auto tile size add-on for setting tile sizes...automatically.

Comment: @Fly_7113 I agree with pycoder ;)
Also note that rendering in cycles can take even months.... for a normal project here is an exam (he says in vid description that took him 2 months to render: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hx7q4F3K0Oo ))
If you want you may also try luxrender (plugin + opensource for blender) which has an option for both cpu and gpu but it is more advanced and can be difficult to use if you are new.

Answer (score 1):

A GPU can usually render faster than a CPU.Try rendering a single frame with your gpu and then your cpu and see witch one is faster.